# Integration over elliptical integrals

Tags: integration

I have elliptical integral of 2nd kind as given below, $ E(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \lambda^2 \sin^2 \theta} \:  d\theta \: = \: \frac{\pi}{2} \: \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \: \bigg(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\bigg)^2 \frac{\lambda^{2n}}{1 - 2n} $

I have to integrate it again over $ d\theta $ such as,
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} E(\lambda) \: d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \lambda^2 \sin^2 \theta} \:  d\theta \: d\theta$$ Which can not be solved easily.

Since, $ E(\lambda)$ after integration is function of $ \lambda $ not $ \theta$ any more, so can I solve directly as, 
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} E(\lambda) \: d\theta = E(\lambda) \: \theta |_{0}^{\pi/2} = E(\lambda)\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Any help is highly appreciated .

Comment: Are you sure that you wanted to integrate the elliptic integral over $\theta$ and not over $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I formulated the exact problem above.

Comment: If so, then it's correct.

Comment: My apologies,  I can not get the point how both solutions have same meaning.

Comment: The $\theta$ in the 2 integrals are different variables so you should change your notation